# Get example program or tutorial for backup everything in android?

Tags: java, android, backup

Where to get example program or tutorial for backup everything in android phone to database as files? any help is appreciated and Thanks in advance...

Comment: Back up everything in a database as files... Did you consider the space such database is going to use?

Comment: You cant!!! Daabase has memory chunk from your phone how can you backup everything in your databse from your phone? Logic

Comment: no... If i use to backup in database as files such as contacts, media, settings then further i'd upload it through FTP into a server

Comment: So, there is not possibility to back up the files from phone?

Comment: Refer these links: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/index.html

Comment: can refer this link as android support backup facility http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the phone is rooted, you cannot access to other apps data.

For more info looks here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Comment: rooted? does that word have a special synonym?

Comment: rooted : it means removing all security levels to files.

Comment: thank you... But we should give any permissions to achieve it? Coz i have already backed up contacts and settings as files

Comment: as the first link show it to you, the data "backupable" are provide using "contents provider", others apps data aren't accessible except when the phone is rooted.

Comment: oh ok so, if we root the phone(i.e make the application authenticated to access the files) it is possible right?